# Path error with "\"

Tags: c#, path

"No english native user"
When I make a path or a name instance for a SQL Server name on Visual Studio/C#, it marks the "\" as a error.

This is the error line:
[image]

It needs that "\" to work but it says it's a UTF-16 sequence. How to I fix this?
[image]

Comment: You need to escape \ character as it's a c# string. Just replace \ with \\

Answer (score 0):

You can put „@„ before string  e.g. @”data source=\ ...” or change ”/” to ”//”

Comment: Change "\" to "\\"

Answer (score 0):

Just replace "\" with "\" or add "@" in front of your string
Ex:

```
str = "C:\\Users\\Binh\\Desktop\\C#\\test";
```

Or

```
str = @"C:\Users\Binh\Desktop\C#\test";
```